# Creating table in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html-table

I want to make a table with the same number of rows and columns, but something doesn't work. Could someone check my code please?

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var table = $("<table></table>");
    var columns = 16;
    var rows =16;
    for (var x = 0; x < rows; x++) {
        $("<tr></tr>").appendTo(table);
        for (var y = 0; y < columns; y++) {
            $("<td></td>").appendTo($("<tr></tr>"));
        }
        table.appendTo(".container");
    }
});
```

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rawrins/27w1smhv/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store the row as a variable, to populate it with cells each time. Then you need to append the row to the table after looping through the cells. When you append the table to the `.container` element, you have to do that after the row loop is complete too. Here's your new code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var table = $("<table border='1'>");
  var columns = 16;
  var rows =16;
  for (var x = 0; x < rows; x++) {
    var row = $("<tr>");
    for (var y = 0; y < columns; y++) {
      row.append("<td>");
    }
    row.appendTo(table);
  }
  table.appendTo(".container");
});
```

And a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/79Ly3tk1/

Comment: One more question, if I wanted to add class to the table cells, where I would have to put it in the code?
row.addClass("").append("<td>")?

Comment: It would be `row.append($("<td>").addClass('class'));`

Comment: Thank you for this, but new problem appeared. When I hover this class, the whole row changes its color instead of one cell. Why?

Comment: Sounds like a different issue - without seeing your code, I would guess with the CSS. Here's the fiddle with the class `hoverable` added to cells, and CSS that targets `.hoverable:hover` to add a red background: https://jsfiddle.net/ta0u2uvv/. As you can see in the fiddle, only the cells are affected - not the rows. If your problem still exists, I'd suggest posting it as another question with the rest of your code that impacts it.